# Why is twilight called "Bein Hashmashot"?

Tags: zemanim, language

Inspired by [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/91392/5275), I'm curious why halachic literature calls twilight בין השמשות, which means, literally, "between the two suns"? The sun has set, and there is just one sun, anyway. What do they mean by saying "two suns"?

I understand that the twighlight period is considered *safek* (doubtful) day or night. But, night is the **absence** of the sun. What does it mean by referring to "two suns" and being "between" them?

Comment: See the etimology of Maharal and Gra here: https://he.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/בין_השמשות_(יהדות)#אטימולוגיה

Comment: I could only find the (otherwise quite witty) 404 page there

Comment: @Kazibácsi Oops! I deleted my question before you tried the link. Sorry about that. I'll be deleting my reference, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. According to Kipa [here](http://www.kipa.co.il/%D7%A9%D7%90%D7%9C-%D7%90%D7%AA-%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%91/%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A2-%D7%A0%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%90-%D7%91%D7%99%D7%9F-%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%9B%D7%9A/) the reason is that it is after the sun ("Shemesh of the day") finishes lighting up the sky and before the moon ("Shemesh of the night") lights up the sky.  Therefore, this time period is between the "two suns".

   This name makes perfect sense, as the "sun of the day" is not fully gone, but the "sun of the night" hasn't fully arrived, so it is a Safek if it is the time of the old Shemesh (of the day), or the new Shemesh (of the night).
2. According to Wikishiva [here](https://www.yeshiva.org.il/wiki/index.php?title=%D7%91%D7%99%D7%9F_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%AA), it is between when the sun disappears, and when it's light goes away:

   > ביאור השם "בין השמשות" הוא: הזמן שבין שקיעת גוף השמש ובין העלם אור השמש, כלומר: בין שתי "שמשות"‏

   This would also make sense - the setting of the sun could be the end of the day, and darkness could be the beginning of the night.

Comment: For half the month the moon isn't even visible after Bein Hashemashot

Comment: @DoubleAA obviously it's not a statement of the literally occurring phenomenon

Comment: I hadn't considered that the first explanation is relying on using a "synonym" of Breishit referring to both the sun and the moon as a *ma'or*.

Comment: @DanF although then it should technically be "Bein Hameorot"...

Comment: @רבותמחשבות I guess that's why you listed a 2nd reason ;-) There may be another definition of *shemesh* that fits into what reason #1 is saying.

Comment: Possible explanation, see https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/38006/5275

Comment: @DanF Great find, that fits the first explanation really well.